# Is it possible to disregard the standard drag and drop cursors during an HTML drag operation?

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I am using the HTML drag and drop API to facilitate the resizing of columns in a table.  When the user starts to drag a column, though, the cursor changes to one of the standard drag and drop effects (move, none, etc).  I'd like the cursor to remain the way it was before the drag event was initiated.  Is this possible using the drag and drop events, or will I have to fake the drag and drop using other events like click and mousemove?

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with css

```
.elementClass {
    cursor: normal;
}
```